# determining $n$ in a given sequence $\frac{1+3+5+...+(2n-1)}{2+4+6+...+(2n)} =\frac{2011}{2012} $

Tags: summation

Given that: $$\frac{1+3+5+...+(2n-1)}{2+4+6+...+(2n)} =\frac{2011}{2012} $$
Determine $n$.[image]

The memorandum says the answer is 2011 but how is that so? Where did I go wrong?

Comment: What are $a$ and $d$? Also the numerator might not be $2011$ and the denominator $2012$. It could be $\frac{4022}{4024}$ for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Numerator :
\begin{eqnarray*}
T_n &=& 1+3+5+...+(2n-1)\\
&=& 2+4+6+...+2n - n\\
&=& 2(1+2+3+...+n) - n\\
&=& 2\frac{n(n+1)}{2} - n\\
&=& n^2
\end{eqnarray*}

Similarly for denominator (check) :
\begin{eqnarray*}
B_n &=& 2+4+6+...+2n\\
&=& n(n+1)
\end{eqnarray*}

But it back in the initial equation and you get :
$$\frac{n^2}{n(n+1)} = \frac{2011}{2012} \Longrightarrow 2012n = 2011(n+1)$$

Last line is easy enough to solve.

So in fact the fraction is written in the form $$\frac{4044121}{4046132} = \frac{2011}{2012}$$
I hope this explains well enough why assuming the sums are $2011$ and $2012$ is wrong.

Comment: What did you do in the second line of your solution?

Comment: I added $1$ to each of the element and there are $n$ of them so I subtracted by $n$ at the end so that the equality is still valid. Check for $n = 3$ and $4$ if you want to convince yourself.

Comment: OK. I figured out what you did, but how did you decide to subtract by $n$? How did you know you had to do that and not by 1?

Comment: The sum contains $n$ terms. If I add $1$ to each, that's like adding $n$. Imagine you have $n$ people and you decide to give $1$ coin to each, you'll need $n$ coins. Because I have an equality, I need to adjust it so that's why I subtracted by $n$ after. Effectively, I added $0 = n-n$

Comment: If you are still not convinced, you could check that link which explains why the sum of odd numbers is $n^2$. http://demo.activemath.org/ActiveMath2/search/show.cmd?id=mbase://LeAM_calculus/proofs_school/ex_induction

Answer (score 0):

$1 + 3 + 5 + .. + 2n - 1 = n^2$, and $2 + 4 + ... + 2n = n(n + 1) = n^2 + n$. So:

$\dfrac{n^2}{n^2 + n} = \dfrac{2011}{2012}$. So: $2012n^2 = 2011n^2 + 2011n$, and $n^2 = 2011n$. So $n = 2011$